# DX9 Deferred Rendering, GBuffer displays as clear color only

Tags: c++, directx9, effects, deferred-rendering, rendertargets

I'm trying to implement Catalin Zima's Deferred Renderer in a very lightweight c++ DirectX 9 app (only renders a skydome and a model), at this moment I'm trying to render the gbuffer, but I'm having a problem, the screen shows only the clear color, no matter how much I move the camera around.

However, removing all the render target operations lets the app render the scene normally, even if the models are being applied the renderGBuffer effect.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It can be that the render target type does not allow it to be drawn as a normal sprite on screen. I had a similar problems, but was while using XNA. Can you show the code where you set up your GBuffer render target?

Comment: @RoyT.  I create the render targets as                        `d3ddev>CreateTexture(width,height,1,D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET,D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,&colorRT,NULL)`                                               then I call this function to convert the render target texture to a surface:                                                       `void SetRenderTargetAux(int index,IDirect3DTexture9* textureRT)
 {
  IDirect3DSurface9* surface;
  textureRT->GetSurfaceLevel(0,&surface);
  d3ddev->SetRenderTarget(index,surface);
  surface->Release();
 }`

Comment: As a little note, if I try render only the skydome (with and without trying to set the gbuffer), the app will only draw the clear color too, but also VS2010's "results" window will show many continuous exception warnings.

Comment: What exceptions exactly? We need a lot more information!

Comment: I got the exceptions sorted out, it was just my machine being really clogged up, so much that VS started acting weird. Now to the important stuff, I wanted to see if there was really anything inside the render targets, so I set up a "control" scene (normally rendered), then I try to render a skydome with the deferred method, and after resolving the render targets I draw a world space quad and apply the color render target's content as it's texture, and [here's](http://tinypic.com/r/14o8v4o/6) the result.

Comment: As you can see, the quad's UV seems to be quite messed up (I need to fix that for the actual fullscreen quad), and then there is a clear color 'arch' in front of it, that's supposed to be the skydome seen from the outside.

Comment: The fullscreen quad is now rendering properly, but the quad itself is pure white, seemingly the shader isn't affecting it at all, maybe you encountered something similar @RoyT.?

Comment: Fire31 you really need to give tons and tons more info here :). I haven't encountered a white quad, any idea where the white is coming from, is it the clear color? What exactly is your method and where do you think the problem is.